# Who is the "you" in Isaiah 55:5?

Tags: isaiah, referent-identification

Isaiah 55:5
English Standard Version

> Behold, you shall call a nation that you do not know, and a nation that did not know you shall run to you, because of the LORD your God, and of the Holy One of Israel, for he **has glorified you**.

Who is this "you"?

Answer (score 1):

The antecedents of all the pronouns in Isa 55 is defined in the first few verses:

> **1** “Come, all you who are thirsty, come to the waters; and you without money, come, buy, and eat!  Come, buy wine and milk without
> money and without cost!  **2** Why spend money on that which is not
> bread, and your labor on that which does not satisfy?  Listen
> carefully to Me, and eat what is good, and your soul will delight in
> the richest of foods.

I think that Jesus may have had this passage in mind when He uttered the famous beatitudes, in particular Matt 5:3, 6:

> **3** “Blessed are the poor in spirit, for theirs is the kingdom of heaven.
>
> **6** Blessed are those who hunger and thirst for righteousness, for they will be filled.

Thus, Isa 55 and the beatitudes are a series of promises and blessings upon those who sense their great need, who "*hunger and thirst for righteousness*".

It is these who sense their need of Jesus, His grace and kindness, who understand something of their hopelessness, to whom Jesus gives good things.  Isa has been a great source of comfort to those prepared to confess and partake of Christ's free offer of righteousness, 1 John 1:9.